# Using expand on Parent type navigation property

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have entity defined as follows (details  omitted):

```
public class Order : Cart, IEntity
{


}
```

The base class Cart has a Navigation Property Order Items:

```
public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Using Odata protocol how can I access the Parent types Item property using the expand statement? When I perform the following query

```
https://localhost/ECommerceOData.svc/Order?$expand=Items
```

I get the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code></code>
    <message xml:lang="en-GB">Error processing request stream. The property name 'Items' specified for type 'Bsi.Cloud.eCommerce.Model.Context.Order' is not valid.</message>
</error>
```

Also the `DBContext` exposes Order as a `DBSet`. The Odata service exposes the Order entity:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Order", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
```

Comment: Could you please try to grab the stack trace of the exception (on the server) and share that?

Comment: Another question - is your Entity Set actually named Order, or did the URL get copied incorrectly? In addition to the exception it might be nice to see relevant parts of $metadata if you can share that.